# Change PHP variable with HTMLs <select> <option> OnChange and execute mysql query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, pdo

Hi I currently have 2 < select>
The first one is filled from a button action from the page before and a database query. Depending on what you choose in the first < select>, the second < select> should get filled from a database query with the value of the first < select>. (I am using PDO prepare so I only need to change the parameter to whatever value the selected  has)
I already know how I can get the values into javascript but I don't know how I can then write it into the php variable and execute the mysql query. As javascript is a client-side language, I don't think it's possible to execute the query there so I would need to get it to php somehow?
Select 1:

```
<select name = "select1" class = "select" size = "10" onChange = "function()">
    <?php
        while ($result1 = $query1->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { 
    ?>
    <option value = "
        <?php 
            echo $result1->id; 
        ?>">
        <?php 
            echo $result1->text;
        ?>
    </option>
    <?php } ?>
</select>
```

Select 2:

```
<select name = "select2" class = "select" size = "10" onChange = "function(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
        <?php
        while ($result2 = $query2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)) { ?>
        <option value = "
            <?php 
                echo $result2->id . ";" . $result2->text . ";" . $result2->text2 . ";" . $result2->text3; 
            ?>">
            <?php
                echo $result2->text;
            ?>
        </option>
        <?php } ?>
    </select>
```

If you are curious, function is just displaying some divs and writing the values into some textboxes:

```
        var str = select.split(";");
        document.getElementById("div1").className = "";
        document.getElementById("div2").className = "div";
        document.getElementById("div3").className = "div";
        document.getElementById("div4").className = "div";
        document.getElementById("txt1").value = str[0];
        document.getElementById("txt2").value = str[1];
        document.getElementById("txt3").value = str[2];
        document.getElementById("txt4").value = str[3];
```

php database query to fill select 1:

```
try { 
    $query1 = $db->prepare('SELECT id, text FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl0 USING(id) WHERE id = ?');
    $query1->execute(array($_POST['id']));
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    log_error($ex);
    $arrError[] = "Error SQL 1";
}
```

php database query to fill select 2:

```
try { 
    $query2 = $db->prepare('SELECT id, text, text2, text3 FROM tbl1 INNER JOIN tbl2 USING(id) WHERE id = ?');
    $query2->execute(array($IDFROMSELECT1));
} catch(PDOException $ex) {
    log_error($ex);
    $arrError[] = "Error SQL 2";
}
```

How can I get the id (option value) from select 1 into the $IDFROMSELECT1 variable in php mysql query 2?

Any tips are much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use AJAX to send the value of the select box to a PHP script which will run the query and send back the result. AJAX is easiest done with the jQuery library.

The javascript to run in onchange() would be something like this:

```
    var selectedValue = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({url: "getData.php",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: {id: selectedValue},
        success: function(returnedData) {
            //do something here with returned data
        }
    });
```

In the PHP script (getData.php), you would execute your select like normal, put the results into an array, then return that array as JSON (Javascript Object Notation). This will put the results of the query into a format that you can work with in javascript (in this case, adding the returned results to another select box)

```
$json = json_encode($returnArray);
echo $json;
```

Comment: I now have a very very basic html index site which just hold a single < select> with the options value1 and value2 both as value and displayed text. Also included jQuery via Google CDN. Then I have used your ajax script and in getData.php I have your 2 php lines. Inside "succes function" I have an alert(returnedData), but it isn't doing anything. When I add "alert(selectedValue);" after the first function line it doesn't do anything. When I call the function with "OnChange = "function(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" and then inside the function do an "alert(select);" I get the value.

Comment: in getData.php I have changed $returnArray to $_POST['selectedValue']

Comment: I ment "$_POST['id']"

Comment: Got it working now if I call the function like "func(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)" and create the function like "function(selectedValue)"